# Dynamically created input components do not show model values

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra, icefaces-3

I have some fields of a bean that I need to show programmatically. Is something like this:

```
         HtmlPanelGrid panel = new HtmlPanelGrid();
         panel.setColumns(4);

         HtmlOutputLabel fieldOut = new HtmlOutputLabel();
         fieldOut.setId("fieldOutId");
         fieldOut.setValue("name");
         panel.getChildren().add(fieldOut);
         HtmlInputText fieldIn = new HtmlInputText();
         fieldIn.setId("fieldInId");
         fieldIn.setPartialSubmit(true);
         fieldIn.setValueExpression(
          "field", UtilFaces.createValueExpression("#{newElementBean.fieldName}",String.class));

         panel.getChildren().add(fieldIn); 
         mainForm.getChildren().add(panel);
```

In newElements.xhtml i've defined a form which is binded to mainForm, in this way:

```
    <ice:form binding="#{newElementBean.mainForm}">
  <ice:inputText id="ANOTHERFIELD" value="#{newElementBean.anotherField}"/>
  <ice:commandButton  action="#{newElementBean.save}"  value="Save"/>
</ice:form>
```

When I click on the save button and I go to the next view, the field "ANOTHERFIELD"  has taken the value from the bean, and shows up correctly, but the fields that were dinamically generated shows empty. Its values in the backing bean also are null. It's like the `ValueExpression` is not working for the `HtmlInputText` that I created in the backing bean. I'm using Icefaces 3.3 with Mojarra 2.1.17.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: when are you creating the fields?

Comment: In a previous bean, i get the bean with newElementBean = (NewElementBean)UtilFaces.getBean("newElementBean"), then i create the fields and set to the bean with newElementBean.setMainForm(form).

Comment: The scope of these beans is @CustomScoped(value = "#{window}"). I tried with noneScope or sessionScope, just for seeing if the values were correct, but didnt work.

Comment: I have news. The setValueExpression is wrong, the first parameter must be "value" (fieldIn.setValueExpression("value", UtilFaces.createValueExpression("#newElementBean.fieldName}",String.class))). Is not resolved yet, right now the field is showing the text "#{newElementBean.fieldName}".

Comment: SOLVED!! I cannot post the answer because of my reputation :-(. In a few words,the first parameter of the setValueExpression must be "value". My second mistake was that my createValueExpression method was incorrect. In this link, at the bottom, you will find the method that works for me.

Comment: I did not put the link. Here is it. https://gist.github.com/salikes/3728993/raw/902504805767dcc69a765f52b355b51107621a47/PersistStateDataModel.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I made two mistakes:

1. The proper `setValueExpression` call is like this:

   ```
   fieldIn.setValueExpression("value", UtilFaces.createValueExpression("#newElementBean.fieldName}");
   ```

   I was incorrectly using `"field1"` as 1st argument instead of `"value"`.
2. This is not visble in the question, but my `createValueExpression()` helper method was also wrong. The following is working for me:

   ```
   public static ValueExpression createValueExpression(String expression) {
       Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
       ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
       ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
       return elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
   }
   ```